# Is there a way I can cut out any values less than a score of 6 (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I am doing a graph with movie genres and their average scores and it is a bit hard to understand due to the grouping of it all. I was wondering if there is a way to make it more presentable. I was thinking it might help to cut out any genre (either completely or into an 'other' sub-set) but all my attempts to do so have failed. Here is the code I used to get the graph:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Genre":dataYearScore['Genre'], "Score": dataYearScore['Score']})
df5 = df5.assign(Genre=df5['Genre'].str.split(',')).explode('Genre').reset_index(drop=True)

genre_list5 = []
avg_scores5 = []

for genre in df5["Genre"].unique():
    genre_list5.append(genre)
    avg_scores5.append(df5.loc[df5["Genre"]==genre, "Score"].mean())

plt.bar(genre_list5, avg_scores5, width = 0.8)
plt.xlabel('Genre')
plt.ylabel('Average Score')
plt.xticks(rotation=65)
plt.title('Average Score for Each Genre')
plt.show()
```

This is what my image looks like currently.

[image: Image here]

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df5 = df5[df5['Score']<6]
```